# Locate specific words on a webpage and send notification when found

Tags: python

I am unable to successfully create code that finds a specific word on a single webpage. I haven't gotten anywhere near as far as I'd like, but the overall end goal is when a specific word on a webpage appears, an email will be sent to me.

I am new to coding and googling up the planet and can't find anything that seems to work. At the most I am able to get the webpage to load.

```
import urllib
import pprint

words = ['DiCaprio']
site = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.msn.com/')
for word in words:
    if word in site:
       pprint(word)
    else:
       pprint(word, "not found")
```

I get the below error. I'm not sure if my code is in the ballpark or in a football field blocks away. Lol!

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gerar/Documents/Program Builds/PyCharm/Test/Testing.py", line 5, in 
    site = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.msn.com/')
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request)?

Answer (score 0):

You can open page and get page source by Selenium.
Install selenium and webdriver_manager before run:

```
    pip install selenium
    pip install webdriver_manager
```

Then try this:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

    # if you don't want to see, how browser opens page, use headless flag
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)

    words = ['DiCaprio']
    driver.get('https://www.msn.com/')
    src = driver.page_source
    for word in words:
        if word in src:
            pprint.pprint(word)
        else:
            pprint.pprint(word, "not found")
```

Comment: The error sounds as if it does not know what webdriver_manager is. It returned the following. Do I have to put in the coding where the chrome driver is? The chromedriver.exe is currently on my desktop: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gerar/Documents/Program Builds/PyCharm/Test/Testing.py", line 2, in <module>
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'

Comment: make 'pip install webdriver_manager' in the terminal before run

Comment: Thanks! I'll google that. This is all pretty new to me.

Comment: Okay, I finally figured out how to install the webdriver manager but PyCharm doesn't seem to be able to find it.   from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'

Comment: 1. Open Edit Configuration of PyCharm https://ibb.co/HYz4F0K
2. Remember Python interpreter https://ibb.co/HTPYfRp
3. Close it and open File -> Settings https://ibb.co/cts8hpT
4. For interpreter which are you using check webdriver-manager https://ibb.co/ThP9RfL
5. If you don't have it, click on '+', enter webdriver-manager and install it https://ibb.co/3d2Js7t